# итерирование нескольких (3 и более) срезов (векторов, массивов) одновременно без bounds check

Tags: rust, итераторы, slice

Мои неглубокие знания в `rust` говорят, что `Iterator::zip` позволяет итерировать два контейнера одновременно. Вопрос: существует ли способ итерировать 3 и более контейнера одновременно без `bounds check`?

Есть очевидный способ сделать `v1.iter().zip(v2).zip(v3)`, но есть ли более эргономичные варианты?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Не очень понятно чем не устраивает ваш вариант, но у пакета `itertools` есть макрос `izip`

```
// iterate over three sequences side-by-side
let mut results = [0, 0, 0, 0];
let inputs = [3, 7, 9, 6];

for (r, index, input) in izip!(&mut results, 0..10, &inputs) {
    *r = index * 10 + input;
}

assert_eq!(results, [0 + 3, 10 + 7, 29, 36]);
```